# onclicked method is not defined when it is in a window.onload function

Tags: javascript, html

My onclick Method is defined, however I get an not defined error.

I want to call a funtion in my javascript file which is surrounded by a window. onload= funktion() but when i click the checkbox this error occurs:Uncaught ReferenceError: handleAverageHight is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html?ID=1:50)

```
window.onload=function(){

     var cb= document.getElementById('showAverage');
    //shows the average high or remove it 
                function handleAverageHight() {

                    //do something
                }
};
```

my html where I want to call it:

```
<div class="form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label" >
                            <input id="show2D" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value=""/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: A function defined inside another function is "private" to that enclosing function, and not visible outside of it.

Comment: where have you bound the onclick?

Comment: `window.onload() {...}`, why not `window.onload = function() {...}`?

Comment: As @Pointy writes, the function is "private", because you define it in another function scope. To expose the function as "public" prefix the function with "window": window.handleAverageHight. There you assign the "window" object a new property which is a function and can be reached from your DOM elements.

Comment: Please show where you define the `onclick`. That's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the **handleAverageHight()** function inside another function. In JavaScript, when you declare a variable or function inside a function, it is not accessible outside of that function. This is called **Local Scope**. If you declare a variable or function outside, it is accessible to everywhere. It is called **Global Scope**. As you have declared the **handleAverageHight** function inside a function, you can not refer this function outside of it. So that error occurred.

You can fix it in two ways.

**Method-01:**
Use `element.addEventListener()` inside `window.onload` function.

```
window.onload = function(){
    cb = //your check box

    function handleAverageHight(){
        // Your code goes here
    }

    cb.addEventListener("click", handleAverageHight);
}
```

**Method-02:**
Use **handleAverageHight** as a global variable and use **onclick** attribute to the element. [Not Recommended]

JS:

```
var handleAverageHeight;
window.onload = function(){
    cb = //your check box

    handleAverageHight = function(){
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="handleAverageHeight()" />
```

Comment: Is it a bad solution when i just put the handleAverageHeight function out of the window.onload even when all my other methods are still in the window.onload function?

Comment: Yes. This solution is not recommended. It creates a global variable and pollutes the global namespace. So always try to use the first one.